# How to pass a Whole Query as Variable (More Specifically Method Parameter) in the @Query annotation in SpringBoot JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So I want to create a String based on some conditions and pass the whole query as method argument. Now I found out about SPeL and a Syntax :

```
@Query(value = "#{#query}", nativeQuery = true)
List<User> findByQuery(@Param("query") String query);
```

but that thing gave me a error:

```
Java.sql.SQLException: Statement.executeQuery() cannot issue statements that do not produce result sets
```

The Query I passed:

```
SELECT * FROM registration WHERE APPROVED='pending' ORDER BY RSID DESC LIMIT 5
```

Though the whole query can change depending on a particular condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I finally got the answer.
To run a query using the EntityManager class in Spring Boot, you can follow these steps:

1. Inject the EntityManager instance into your class using the @PersistenceContext annotation:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

2. Use the createQuery() method of the EntityManager instance to create a query object. You can pass a JPQL (Java Persistence Query Language) query string or a native SQL query string as a parameter:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.salary > :salary");
query.setParameter("salary", 50000);
```

3. If you are using a native SQL query, you can use the createNativeQuery() method instead:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE salary > :salary", Employee.class);
query.setParameter("salary", 50000);
```

4. Call the getResultList() method on the query object to execute the query and return the results:

```
List<Employee> employees = query.getResultList();
```

5. You can then iterate over the list of results and process them as needed:

```
for (Employee employee : employees) {
    // process each employee object
}
```

Note that you should always use parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection attacks. The EntityManager class supports both JPQL and native SQL queries, but JPQL is recommended because it is database-independent and provides better type-safety.